# Error: Attempted to read or write protected memory this is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, ssas

I am getting the error stating in title in the following program.
I am trying to impersonate the user.
Here my code base.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;



namespace cubeStructure
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            connectToServer();
        }
        private static void connectToServer()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to server...");
                XmlaClient oConn = new XmlaClient();
                Boolean validUser = false;
                validUser = impersonateValidUser("haadmin", "HAICPM", "ha05admin");
                if (validUser)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("User Aethunticated");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed");
                }
                string connectionString = "Provider=MSOLAP.3;Data Source=192.168.136.233\\sql2008;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksDW";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern Boolean RevertToSelf();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern long CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int LogonUserA(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, IntPtr phToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, int ImpersonationLevel, IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);
        public static WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;

        public static bool impersonateValidUser(string userName, string domain, string password)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Going Step 1");
            try
            {
                bool functionReturnValue = false;
                int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
                int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
                WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity = default(WindowsIdentity);
                IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
                IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
                functionReturnValue = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Going Step 2");
                if (RevertToSelf())
                {   
                    if (LogonUserA("haadmin", ".", "ha05admin", LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, token) != 0)
                    {   
                        if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                        {
                            tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                            impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                            if ((impersonationContext != null))
                            {
                                functionReturnValue = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!tokenDuplicate.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                }
                if (!token.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    CloseHandle(token);
                }
                return functionReturnValue;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting exception at logonUserA method.
Is there any thing wrong while adding the dlls into code?
Can any one please help me in this context.

Thanks

Comment: Please make your question a lot more specific, *to start with* where in your code does this exception occur?

Comment: Too many bugs in the pinvoke declarations.  Using LogonUserA with CharSet.Auto is one of them.  Visit pinvoke.net to find good ones.

Comment: @HansPassant There are plenty of poorly written p/Invoke declarations on pinvoke.net. This website is really helpful, but I wouldn't rely too much on it.

Comment: @All.. thanks for your help. the mistake i made here is need to give the refernce for the logonusera method as LogonUserA( string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain,  string lpszPassword,  int dwLogonType,  int dwLogonProvider,  ref IntPtr phToken)... the same thing is applicable to DuplicateToken method also...